# Vue+Vuex+Axios API calls handle multiple updates

Tags: vue.js, frontend, axios

I'm new at development and I have a 2 questions.

First One is:

1) I have a dashboard that make a call to back-end and create charts, but my database updates new informations from another program and I have to constantly make calls to data base to update my dashboard. My question is Do I have to make a infinite loop or there is a better way like send a event from the back-end to make the call again?

Number 2:

2) I have a list of movies that was shared with many users. When user A make a change on this list and saves on the database. The user b and c has to see the new information. Do I have to make the infinity loop or can I use some event?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket

Answer (score 1):

The "infinite loop", or better known as polling, is by far the simplest approach. It's not perfect, but do you need perfect?

The alternative is to use database "triggers" or "events". If your database supports it, you can hook up functions to be called whenever your database updates. Then you can push updates to the client through websockets. This may be worth it if polling is an expensive operation, but it's more work, takes more time to implement, more bugs, etc.